# Bug in DevOps project creation with Python

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When i try to create a new DevOps project from Azure portal by clicking Python as my new application, Django as framework and Web App for Containers as service, i cannot click on "additional settings" button while filling in project details. I have tried 2 seperate accounts and all the available browsers but the behaviour is the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Went through the error details using inspect element. It turns out the script was looking for a devops organization linked to the account - which i did not have. So i created a devops organization and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug, the `Additional settings` work fine on my side, please try again. Besides, I notice your subscription is a free version, may be you could try to use another one.

[image]

**Update**:

As @Ali Maan said, you should create a devops organization first then it will work fine.